# Solve for a z complex number z in $z^4+16i=0$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Note: I have to show the solutions in the form $\rho\cdot cis(\theta)$

I did:

$$z^4+16i=0 \Leftrightarrow \\
z^4 = -16i\Leftrightarrow \\
z^4=16cis(-\frac{\pi}{4}) \Leftrightarrow \\
z = 2cis(\frac{-\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi}{4}) \Leftrightarrow \\
z = 2cis(\frac{-\pi+8k\pi}{16})$$

But my book's solutions differ. What went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Actually $-i = 0 + i(-1) = cis(-\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Answer (score 1):

$-i=cis(-\frac{\pi}{2})$; the vector $(0, -1)$ corresponds to a $90$ degree clockwise rotation from the positive real line.